# unable to start service from AsyncTask

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I am trying to start service from AsyncTask but cant see that its starts. I also added Service on manefast file.

here the code:

```
protected Integer  doInBackground(Void... values) throws InterruptedException {
    //starts service number activite
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
    serviceIntent.setAction("services.conServise");
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

and the manifest file:

```
   <service android:name="services.conServise"></service>

  </application>
```

thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`services.conServise`  should be in a `<action>` tag within the `<intent-filter>` tag for that declaration of service, please replace *servicesclassname* with the appropriate package name for example, *org.mypkg.foo.bar*.

```
<service android:name="<servicesclassname>">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="services.conServise"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it via onPostExecute() method in AsyncTask class. Thanks