# Android ASyncTask and service

Tags: android

How I can start my service in ASyncTask
for example

```
MyTask task = new MyTask();
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class),    task);
```

What is correct way to do this?

I want to tell service in which threads are executed

Comment: That makes no sense... Why would you pass a task to `startService`? What do you want to do?

Comment: then what problem are you facing in it?

Comment: See this post , its having similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168172/unable-to-start-service-from-asynctask

Answer (score 0):

Quote from Android dev. :

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI
>   thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

I guess if you're not using directly startService, is that you want start it in a new thread, no ?
If so, you should do a new thread :

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
public void run(){
getApplicationContext().bindService(
        new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YOURSERVICE.class),
        serviceConnection,
        Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE
    );
}
};
t.start();
```