# how to make a Service and AsyncTask communicate

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have this issue:
I have a main activity that is bound to a service,
Also, that main activity can call a class (AsyncTask) that is a client that connects to a server and waits for data.

I tried to make the bind from class (AsyncTask) client to the service,
but I don't know if that's possible
or do I have to return data to the main activity so main activity can send it to the service?

I can do this in the main class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), ChatHeadService.class);
startService(intent);
bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

but how can I implement it in the class (AsyncTask) client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the data from your async task to the main activity this way.

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
}
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
    showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
}
```

Then you can pass that data from activity to service by calling `startService(...)` and passing data in an `intent`.

Calling `startService(...)` multiple times is safe and will not start multiple instances.

**P.S.**
Running a server in Android doesn't sound right to me. Android devices should only be used as clients.

Comment: maybe what im trying to do is not possible with asinc task, because only onpostexecute can return what is done in do in background. And i want to call a service in background and manipulate it without having to close the async task to get the the value passed from the server

Comment: What you're trying to do can be achieved with service

Comment: i added the service and it works but i got an error trying to move the image : Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: @tseres You should not modify views in a service. Talk back to the activity from your service and let it manage the views.

Comment: ok got it main activity is the one that should handle it. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can just invoke the service from `doInBackground()` like you can in the activity. See [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168172/unable-to-start-service-from-asynctask) for a solution to a similar problem.

Comment: im trying to follow that example Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
                serviceIntent.setAction("services.conServise"); Context context = getApplication();
                context.startService(serviceIntent); but context is not recognized maybe think i need the main class so i can work

Comment: @tseres `MainActivity.class`?

Comment: @tseres I believe what they are doing is passing the context in via the constructor for AsyncTask. As an aside, if you do this, you will need to be aware of [these issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3821998/6287910).